# Having trouble calling a get request using Falcon framework

Tags: python, http, pycharm, falconframework, waitress

I'm following [Falcon tutorial](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/tutorial.html) for Python.

Everything worked fine until this part:
[image]

The response I'm getting when trying this command `http localhost:8000/images` is:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Length: 110
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Sat, 01 Dec 2018 15:50:26 GMT
Server: waitress

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an unexpected internal server error

(generated by waitress)
```

I read it's a problem in the code but I can't find it, it's exactly as in the tutorial, `app.py` file:

```
import falcon
from images import Resource
api = application = falcon.API()
images = Resource()
api.add_route('/images', images)`

images.py:

    import json

import falcon


class Resource(object):

    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        doc = {
            'images': [
                {
                    'href': '/images/1eaf6ef1-7f2d-4ecc-a8d5-6e8adba7cc0e.png'
                }
            ]
        }

        # Create a JSON representation of the resource
        resp.body = json.dumps(doc, ensure_ascii=False)

        # The following line can be omitted because 200 is the default
        # status returned by the framework, but it is included here to
        # illustrate how this may be overridden as needed.
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200
```

Also, I have an empty file named `__init__.py` and all the files are in the same folder, `C:\look\look`.

P.S.
I tried to add an HTTP requests scratch file (using PyCharm IDE) but there is no option to add that kind of a file (after I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>). I couldn't find how to fix this anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the question is pretty old, but I found a solution. Just run the server with command:

```
waitress-serve --port=8000 --call look.app:get_app
```

since we get the `app` from calling the function `get_app()`